# spread and destructuring object

Tags: javascript

I have this code :

```
function logInfos(user = {}) {
  const redactedUser = {
    firstName: "<REDACTED>",
    lastName: "<REDACTED>",
    address: {
      city: "<REDACTED>",
      country: "<REDACTED>",
    },
  };

  const {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    address: { city, country },
  } = user;

  console.log("partie user", firstName);
  console.log("partie user", lastName);

  const newUser = {
    ...user,
    address: {
      ...user.address,
    },
  };
  console.log("partie newuser", newUser);

  console.log(`${newUser.firstName} ${newUser.lastName} lives in ${newUser.address.city}, ${newUser.address.country}.`);
}
```

How can I replace the value `undefined` of `user` object passed as argument and use the default value of `redactedUser` object instead?

Comment: i do modify this part of code :  const {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    address: { city, country },
  } = user;

Comment: You'll want to combine the passed `user` with your `redactedUser`. `const newUser = {  ...redactedUser, ...user, address: {...redactedUser.adress, ...user.address}}`

Comment: and I don't have the right to use any condition statement

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use `redactedUser` if `user` is `undefined` or that you want to use e.g. `redactedUser.firstName` if `user` doesn't have a `firstName` property?

Comment: yes, for example, if the firstname is not passed with the user object in argument i want use the fisrtname of redactedUser

Comment: sorry for my english, yes felix kling that's what i want and to answer to pilchard it doesn't work, he replaced all the data by redactedUser object

Comment: thanks for all i resolved my problem with this code ```const {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    address: { city, country },
  } = { ...redactedUser, ...user };

  const newUser = {
    ...redactedUser,
    ...user,
    address: {
      ...redactedUser.address,
      ...user.address,
    },
  };````

Answer (score 1):

```
function compareObj(defaultObj, targetObj) {
for(let key in defaultObj) {
  if(!Array.isArray(defaultObj[key]) && defaultObj[key] !== null && typeof defaultObj[key] === "object") {
    targetObj[key] = {};
    copyObj(defaultObj[key], targetObj[key]); 
  } else {
    if(!targetObj[key]) targetObj[key] = defaultObj[key];
  }
}
```

}

compareObj(redactedUser, user);

**You can place this code function inside logInfos.**
What it does is, it iterates through all the properties of the default object and checks if the property exists in the target object.
In case the property does not exist in the target object, same property will be created in the target object and the value will be copied.